# Single Logout Profile Idp Logout Issue

Tags: java, saml

I am using SAML2.0 with Single Logout Profile. When an SP initiated Logout happens, a `LogoutRequest` is sent from request initiator SP to Ping (Identity Provider), Ping sends SP a `LogoutResponse`. My SP ends its session after that response, but the IdP session is not terminated. At what time does user session with IdP get terminated? Before the SP session or after the session? Right now it is doing a local logout, but I want a global logout where it terminated all SPs session and also IdP session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SP-initialized `SingleLogout` IdP sends back `LogoutRespone` to the original requester **after** it has already terminated sessions with the other session participants. So once you've received the `LogoutResponse`, the IdP session is supposed to be already terminated.

Does the `LogoutResponse` you receive contain Success status code? What binding are you using?

Comment: Yes, the LogoutResponse contains succcess status code. I am using HTTP Redirect binding.